# How to check the version of GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

How to check which version of GitLab is installed on the server?

I am about version specified in GitLab changelog:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

For example: "6.5.0", "6.4.3", etc.

Сan this be done only through the terminal?
Is there a way to do that remotely (with browser instead of terminal)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about a product/web app that has nothing to do with development. I think [webapps.se] is a better place for it.

Comment: For people who are using official GitLab.com, your version is the latest since GitLab is [updated continuously](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release/tasks/-/issues/?_gl=1%2a1osvw75%2a_ga%2aMTc3MDE5ODg4NS4xNjYzNjQxNjIx%2a_ga_ENFH3X7M5Y%2aMTY2OTM1NzIzNy4yMC4xLjE2NjkzNTkyMjEuMC4wLjA.)

Answer (score 523, accepted):

I have updated my server to GitLab 6.6.4 and finally found the way to get version of GitLab remotely without SSH access to server.

You **should be logged in** to access the following page:
`https://your.domain.name/help`

It shows something similar to:

> **GitLab 6.6.4** 42e34ae
>
> GitLab is open source software to collaborate on code.
> ...
> etc.

Comment: You have to be signed in though. (I've been scratching my head on this for 10 minutes...)

Comment: Do you know a way to do this from a filesystem? I.e., a server that no longer boots.

Comment: Find filename "version-manifest.txt"... For gitlab omnibus it is stored at "/opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt"

Comment: Note: you can see what this looks like on the hosted gitlab at https://gitlab.com/help (if you are logged into that service).

Comment: It's sad not work on "https://gitlab.ow2.org/help", maybe it's too old.

Comment: Using grep: grep "gitlab-ce" /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt for community edtion
grep "gitlab-ee" /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt for enterprise edtion

Comment: If logged in, use the Help entry in the question-mark-in-circle dropdown.

Answer (score 143):

For omnibus versions:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info
```

Example:

```
System information
System:     Ubuntu 12.04
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.1.7p400
Gem Version:    2.2.5
Bundler Version:1.10.6
Rake Version:   10.4.2
Sidekiq Version:3.3.0

GitLab information
Version:    8.2.2
Revision:   08fae2f
Directory:  /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter: postgresql
URL:        https://your.hostname
HTTP Clone URL: https://your.hostname/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@your.hostname:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP: yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    2.6.8
Repositories:   /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories
Hooks:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

Comment: It does, but it's SLOW AS HELL. WebURL/help page is much better solution for such a simple task - checking version.

Comment: @stamster OP asked "Сan this be done only through the terminal?"

Comment: What is this command doing that it takes sooo long to get back version info?

Comment: @stamster yes this is slow, but if your running gitlab over a cluster of servers, and if only one server failed the upgrade - you might want to manually check that server.

Answer (score 87):

You can access the version through a URL, the web GUI, and the ReST API.

### Via a URL

An HTML page displaying the version can be displayed in a browser at `https://your-gitlab-url/help`. The version is displayed only if you are signed in.

### Via a menu in the web GUI

If you do not care to type this URL, you can also access the same HTML page from a menu in the GitLab web GUI:

#### In GitLab 11 and later

1. Log in to GitLab
2. Click on the [image: ?] drop down menu in the upper right. Select *Help*.
3. The GitLab version appears at the top of the page

#### In earlier versions, like GitLab 9

1. Log in to GitLab
2. Click on the [image: three lines] drop down menu in the upper left. Select *Help*.
3. And then the version appears at the top of the page

### Via the ReST API

Log in as any user, select the user icon in the upper right of the screen. Select *Settings > Access Tokens*. Create a personal access token and copy it to your clipboard.

In a Linux shell, use `curl` to access the GitLab version:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: personal-access-token" your-gitlab-url/api/v4/version
```

Comment: And then? Can you be more specific. I'm trying to set up python-gitlab as a non-admin but fail to find the API version

Comment: this CURL trick worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Gitlab recommend you use the Metadata API instead of the Version API. It contains additional information and is aligned with the GraphQL metadata endpoint. As of GitLab 15.5, the Version API is a mirror of the Metadata API.

Answer (score 47):

If you are using a self-hosted version of GitLab then you may consider running this command.

`grep gitlab /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt`

Comment: Easiest solution I've seen so far with GitLab self-hosted 12.10.x, thanks much.

Comment: It is better than GitLab recommended answer because does not need to be logged or use URL.

Answer (score 27):

You have two choices (after logged in).

1. Use API url https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/version (you can use it from command line with private token), it returns `{"version":"10.1.0","revision":"5a695c4"}`
2. Use HELP url in browser https://gitlab.example.com/help and you will see version of GitLab, ie `GitLab Community Edition 10.1.0 5a695c4`

Answer (score 24):

You can view GitLab's version at: https://your.domain.name/help

Or via terminal: `gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info`

Answer (score 19):

cd /opt/gitlab

cat version-manifest.txt

Example:

gitlab-ctl         6.8.2-omnibus
gitlab-rails       v6.8.2

Current gitlab version is 6.8.2

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Answer (score 10):

If using the Gitlab Docker image:

```
# from the host, not inside container
sudo cat /srv/gitlab/data/gitlab-rails/VERSION
```

Example output:

```
12.1.3
```

The same file could be found inside the running container under `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/VERSION`

Comment: I think you mean the mapped path, the file is under a running container under /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/VERSION
But yes, it works.

Comment: @sneaky thanks, I clarified my answer

Answer (score 8):

### Get information about GitLab and the system it runs on :

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
```

**Example output of gitlab:env:info**

```
System information
System:     Arch Linux
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  yes
RVM Version:    1.20.3
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p0
Gem Version:    2.0.0
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.0.4

GitLab information
Version:    5.2.0.pre
Revision:   4353bab
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://gitlab.arch
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.arch/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.arch:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.4.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Read this [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/gitlab), it will help you.

Comment: It works, but current directory should be changed before to directory where gitlab is installed: cd /home/git/gitlab (otherwise it will report: Could not locale Gemfile).

Comment: Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (trusty) I can use this command to achieve the same: `gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `http://domain-name/help` you can also check your Gitlab version name in browser by logging as Admin

- Go to `http://domain-name`
- Log in to Gitlab as Admin (`Root`)
- Go to Admin Area
- On the right corner, below `Groups` tab, you can find `Components` tab

There you can find not only Gitlab version but also different components like Gitlab Shell, Gitlab workhorse, Gitlab API etc, version numbers 
[image]
You will also find the suggestions to update the versions there

Answer (score 6):

```
cat /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt |grep gitlab-ce|awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Great option to get the version automatically, though using too much code ;) ... try `awk '$1=="gitlab-ce"{print $2}' /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt` instead.

Comment: that is fantastic!!

Answer (score 4):

It can be retrieved using REST, see [Version API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/version.html) :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/version
```

For authentication see [Personal access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens) documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I have Version: 12.2.0-ee and I tried the URL via  (https://yourgitlab/help ) but  I have not got this information.
In the other hand I got this with gitlab-rake with success into the command line:

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info
```

...
GitLab information
Version:        12.2.0-ee
...

Comment: gitlab.com is also EE and you can easy access https://gitlab.com/help if you are logged in. So you have made something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to paste the following command:

```
cat /opt/gitlab/version-manifest.txt | head -n 1
```

and there you get the version installed. :)

Answer (score 4):

you can use the package manager to query installed version of gitlab-ce. if it happens to be debian or ubuntu, like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep gitlab-ce | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d" " -f3
```

should work similarly with other distributions, assuming you used package manager to install.

Answer (score 3):

this command line to know all the data of your gitlab install

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info
```

and this command line to know are there new Gitlab versions, for you can update gitlab

```
yum --showduplicates list gitlab-ce
```

And once you know your current version and the latest gitlab update, you can update it with the following line command

```
yum install gitlab-ce-15.2.2-ce.0.el7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are an admin and if you want to see the Gitlab version (and more you didn't know about) click on the wrench/admin menu icon and under **Components** you can see a lot , especially if you are using *Omnibus*.

Answer (score 0):

To check the version of gitlab on centos

```
rpm -qa | grep gitlab-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

The following information is available from within the CI pipeline (GitLab >= 11.4):

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| CI_SERVER_VERSION_MAJOR | The major version of the GitLab instance. |
| CI_SERVER_VERSION_MINOR | The minor version of the GitLab instance. |
| CI_SERVER_VERSION_PATCH | The patch version of the GitLab instance. |
| CI_SERVER_VERSION | The full version of the GitLab instance. |