# How to detect gitlab version in gitlab.rb?

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab Omnibus installation, inside the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` configuration script, how can I detect the current version of Gitlab? (I need to enable/disable some features depending on version of Gitlab.)

***edit:*** Please note I need this check to work ***specifically from inside gitlab.rb script!*** The answers described in [How to check the version of Gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068773) are not clearly appropriate for this question out of the box. At least not without some highly non-obvious to me adaptation. If you can demonstrate how any of those applies, *please show it explicitly*, I can't see such a way myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the version of Gitlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068773/how-to-check-the-version-of-gitlab)

Comment: @Hackerman Please note I've edited to explain why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068773 is not a duplicate. At least not without some ***highly nonobvious adaptation***

Comment: I didnt saw any `version` in gitlab.rb file. You might need to come out of `gitlab.rb` file and do as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068773/how-to-check-the-version-of-gitlab) suggests

Comment: @RajanaDeepak `gitlab.rb` is Ruby code, and is loaded by a Ruby script, so it's very much possible, that the loader, being part of Gitlab application, somehow exposes current Gitlab version to `gitlab.rb` code. That would be the perfect solution. Alternatively, maybe some (but not all) answers from "the other question" could be nontrivially adapted as Ruby code that could be used in `gitlab.rb`.