# Scoped labels in Gitlab as badges

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

When looking at the labels used by the Gitlab team itself [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/labels), the scoped labels are rendered similar to badges from [shields.io](https://shields.io/).

[image: Scoped Gitlab labels]

Does anyone know how to get this appearance? Scoped labels can be created by using a double colon "::" but they are rendered as normal text.

Comment: What do the scoped labels look like for you? Can you include an image?

Comment: They are simply rendered as text, e.g. `Area::Devops`

Comment: Did you figure this out? What version of GitLab are you running?

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. Our Gitlab Plan does not include this feature, and that's probably the reason why they are rendered as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search the GitLab documentation for [Scoped Labels](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/labels.html#scoped-labels), you will find that scoped labels were introduced in GitLab Premium 11.10. It is currently only available in GitLab Premium, GitLab.com Silver and higher tiers.

My guess is you're not running one of these versions, otherwise the scoped labels would render and behave as expected by default. See [How to check the version of GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068773/how-to-check-the-version-of-gitlab).

Comment: We also see the plain text rendering, but are using GitLab CE (i.e. Open Source), not GitLab.com hosting.  Since we have the source, no features should be restricted unless the code is just absent.  How can they be enabled via GitLab CE configuration?

Comment: @DavidJ so by that logic you should have access to all premium features for free? I don't believe that is the case. GitLab manages separate code bases/forks for different tiers. They regularly move features into open source, but unfortunately scoped labels is not one of them.

Comment: @DV82XL As for now, scoped labels are not still not open source. Do you see a chance that they will be in future?